# Value of the the sum of reciprocals of combinators

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Evaluate
$$\sum_{n=2009}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ \binom{n}{2009}}$$

I tried making the $r^{th}$ term as a difference of 2 terms, but that didn't work out. Do we need to integrate or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice:
>
> - $$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!\cdot(n-k)!}\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{k!\cdot(n-k)!}{n!}$$
> - $$\sum_{n=a}^{m}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{a\binom{m+1}{k}-(m+1)\binom{a}{k}}{(k-1)\binom{a}{k}\binom{m+1}{k}}$$
> - $$\sum_{n=a}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{a}}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{a\binom{m+1}{a}-m+1}{(a-1)\binom{m+1}{a}}=\frac{a}{a-1}$$

So, in your example $a=2009$:

$$\sum_{n=2009}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2009}}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{2009\binom{m+1}{2009}-m+1}{(2009-1)\binom{m+1}{2009}}=\frac{2009}{2009-1}=\frac{2009}{2008}$$

Answer (score 5):

Yours is a telescoping sum. Write
$$\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2009}} = \frac{2009}{2008} \left( \frac{1}{\binom{n-1}{2008}} - \frac{1}{\binom{n}{2008}}\right)$$
so that your sum is
$$\frac{2009}{2008} \left( 1- \frac{1}{\binom{2009}{2008}} + \frac{1}{\binom{2009}{2008}} - \frac{1}{\binom{2010}{2008}} + \frac{1}{\binom{2010}{2008}} - \dots \right) = \frac{2009}{2008}$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate the first step?

Comment: What is nice with your solution is that you can show that $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ \binom{n}{m}}=\frac{m}{m-1}$

Comment: The solution was wonderful, but could you you please explain how to write the first step from just the question, i mean, i had to prove from the first step that it is same as the question, how did you think such?

Comment: Well, I was simply lucky. I tried (actually for no special reason) to compute $\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}-\frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{k}}$ and found a pattern.